# Jquery UI slider to handle events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to jquery and javascript, but I am looking to do what I think should be a relatively simple task. I want to use the UI Slider widget to control certain actions. Get to value 100, show an image. Get to value 200, destroy the previous image, play a new animation (or show an image). This is what I have written so far: http://jsfiddle.net/LGMHP/14/

Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were missing some dollar signs in front of your jQuery variables. Try:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    step: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value == 100) {
            $('#green').hide();
        };
        if (ui.value == 200) {
            $('#green').hide();
            $('#red').show();
        };

        $("#hour").text(ui.value);
    }
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LGMHP/16/)**.

Comment: Yup, you were absolutely right, and I figured it out right after I posted. One more query, though. I have 13 different animation/image events I was to pass, which would make this a rather lengthy if/else statement. Is there a smarter way to go about this? And thanks for teh quick response, too!

Comment: Typically you'd use if/else or switch/case for something like that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch